# when i restore my data i use pg_restore but it gives me error i tried all the solution

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

```
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "ir_ui_view_group_rel": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ir_ui_view_group_rel_view_id_group_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (view_id, group_id)=(245, 5) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY ir_ui_view_group_rel, line 1
```

Comment: Did you have data in that table before you started the restore? If yes, you need to truncate all tables (or dropping them) before restoring the data. With pg_restore you could do that using the `--clean` option

Comment: i create a new database empty but didn't work

Comment: but all the tables are created when i did the restore and it gives me this error and in odoo nothing open

Comment: One option is data corruption: What do you get for `SELECT view_id, group_id FROM ir_ui_view_group_rel GROUP BY view_id, group_id HAVING count(*) > 1;` on the original database?

Comment: open the table but 0 rows

Comment: "pg_restore" has many options.  Please show us what you are doing.

Comment: Are you loading into the new database you created, or did you create it but then load into a different one?  Normal usage of pg_restore into an empty database will not have the unique index in place during the COPY, but build that index later.